# Makefile conditional rule execution and errors

Tags: makefile

I have a simplified MakeFile with two rules

- check --> performs some checks and prints my error if not successful.
- build --> if "check" is successful performs some task

I can use "exit 1" on "check" rule if the checks aren't successful to avoid the execution of "build" but in this case i cannot find a way to suppress the output.

Basic example:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

build: check
    @gcc $(DEST) -o output_binary

check:
    @[[ -e $(DEST) ]] || { echo "?ERROR"; exit 1;}

.PHONY: build check
```

So how do i avoid "build" to execute if "check" fails and in this case print only my error message instead of the "make" one?

Comment: You can't.  Make is not a scripting language.  You don't get to have full control over everything that it does, like you would with a general purpose interpreted language like shell or python or perl or whatever.  The only thing you can do is put the `check` command inside the same recipe as the `build` commands so that the compile is only run if the check succeeds.

Comment: `check` seems completely pointless; `build` cannot be run if its dependency doesn't exist. Simply set `build` to depend on `$(DEST)`. Are you using this useless recipe as a placeholder for some actually useful code? (Also, weird to call the source `DEST`; and weird to not simply say `build` is a `.PHONY` which depends on `output_binary`, and have `output_binary` depend on its source.)